# mismatch when assigning points to clusters after doing pca or tsne on data

Tags: python

I have some noisy data and that has TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_DATA=65457 points. What I want to do is, to divide them into pieces like having 1000 points in a buffer then I will apply pea to remove the noise and finally I start from the beginning point to the end in the buffer to apply an AI algorithm on them. And again, I collect the next 1000 points from my noisy data and repeat the process until I remove noise from all of those data. Here is my code, However, I don't understand why at the end of running my program, returnedClusterResults=65435 while it should be equal to 65457? Also I found if I change that 1000 to 300 instead, then returnedClusterResults=65239. Can anyone suggest me what can be the problem in my code?

```
class DataPoint_2:

    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


    def get_a(self):
        return self.a
    
    def get_b(self):
        return self.b


    
    def set_cluster(self, clusterNumber):
        self.clusterNumber = clusterNumber
    
    def get_cluster(self):
        return self.clusterNumber

class Centroid_2:

    def __init__(self, a, b):

        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    
    def set_a(self, a):
        self.a = a
    
    def get_a(self):
        return self.a

    def set_b(self, b):
        self.b = b
    def get_b(self):
        return self.b

    def get_distance_2(datapoint , centroid):
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(datapoint.get_a()-centroid.get_a(),2)+ math.pow(datapoint.get_b()-centroid.get_b(),2)
                    )    

    cluster0Data = []
    cluster1Data = []
       
    count0Data=[]
    count1Data=[]
    centroids = []
    
    (inputs , outputs) = load_data()

    for i in range(0,TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_DATA):    
        originalLabels.append(outputs[i])

    for i in range(0,TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_DATA):

        reduced_data=[]
        if len(noisyData_buffer)<1000 and i!=TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_DATA-1:
           noisyData_buffer.append(inputs[i])

        elif len(noisyData_buffer)>=1000 or i==TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_DATA-1:
           pca = PCA(n_components=2)
           noisyData = np.array(noisyData_buffer)
           pca.fit(noisyData)
           reduced_data = pca.transform(noisyData)
###----------------------------------------------------------
           noisyData_buffer=[]
        for f in range(0,len(reduced_data)):
          d = DataPoint_2(float(reduced_data[f][0]) , float(reduced_data[f][1]))

          distances = []
          for k in range(K):
             distances.append(get_distance_2(d , centroids[k]))

          minIndexCalc=minIndexCalc+1  
          min_index = distances.index(min(distances))

          if min_index==0:
                cluster0Data.append(reduced_data[f])
                returnedClusterResults.append(0)

          elif min_index==1:
                cluster1Data.append(reduced_data[f])
                returnedClusterResults.append(1)

            
          centroids[min_index].set_a((d.get_a()+ (clusters[min_index]*centroids[min_index].get_a()))/(clusters[min_index]+1))
          centroids[min_index].set_b((d.get_b()+ (clusters[min_index]*centroids[min_index].get_b()))/(clusters[min_index]+1))

                        
          clusters[min_index] += 1

    return returnedClusterResults
```